# angularjs - script not recognized in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I want to include [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) into my angular app, so I add the js-file in my `main.html` and everything gets displayed correctly. However when I load content from a **template** into main.html, which uses the masonry-specific `js-masonry`class, like this for example:

```
<div id="container" class="js-masonry">
    <div class="item">
      <h2>Im edward</h2>
      <p>im a bird</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

it **doesn't get styled** accordingly like before.
Do I have to somehow include/inject the script into my template directly?
And how would I do that? I tried out [ng-loadscript](https://gist.github.com/endorama/7369006) but I get csp errors from chrome (it's a chrome extension).